# How to set a callback from googlemaps to my native android app?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-webview

In my android app, I plan to let the user pick a location and compute the distance from his current location. So to pick this location, I wanted to give a similar interface like the google maps website, where he searches for an approximate location and then picks the exact location from the map.

Ideally, I would like to launch the google maps application, let the user pick the location and obtain the geo-coordinates back in my app. Is there any way to do this?

If not, Could I achieve this by launching a webview? Is there a way to communicate the location picked from within the webview back to my launch Activity?

The class Geocoder has a method getFromLocationName which gives some results, but they are not as good as the google maps suggestions. So trying to build an equivalent interface as the google maps application does not seem possible.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Ideally, I would like to launch the google maps application, let the user pick the location and obtain the geo-coordinates back in my app. Is there any way to do this?

No, sorry.

> If not, Could I achieve this by launching a webview? Is there a way to communicate the location picked from within the webview back to my launch Activity?

You can inject your own Java objects into the `WebView` using `addJavascriptInterface()`. If you can arrange to get control in JavaScript when the user taps on a point, your JavaScript can invoke that Java object.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The main reason why i wanted to user WebView was to mimic search suggestions like on google maps site. Are you aware of any alternative for search suggestion besides GeoCoder?